# NodeJs tls.createServer equivalent to Apache SSLCertificateChainFile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, ssl, grunt-connect

I have an Apache config for SSL like so:

```
SSLCertificateFile ~/certs/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile ~/certs/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile ~/certs/bundle.crt
```

Now in my NodeJs server, I am using grunt with [grunt-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) as the server.

The documentation for `grunt-connect` says that it can be configured using the following syntax.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        protocol: 'https',
        port: 8443,
        key: grunt.file.read('server.key').toString(),
        cert: grunt.file.read('server.crt').toString(),
        ca: grunt.file.read('ca.crt').toString()
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I need this configuration to match my Apache configurations. It has a certificate file, and a key file, and also a bundle file.

Looking at the documentation for the [tls.createServer](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener) in NodeJs,
I do not see an option that looks like it could be equivalent to `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

How can I make my NodeJs connect server mirror the same SSL configuration as my Apache server?

---

#### EDIT

I will also award the bounty to someone who can do this:

Create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) `Gruntfile` that demonstrates how to  configure `connect` to accept a server certificate *and* bundle certificate.

Comment: What have you been tested so far? What issue are you having?

Comment: @diosney I can start the server, but I get an error when I connect, saying unable to establish a secure connection.
This is because I have not not started connect with the chain file, as I have with Apache.
That's why I need to find out what the equivalent is - or some other way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try concatenating server.crt and ca.crt files in one file and using result in `cert` option. Don't use `ca` option, as per [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener) it is needed only 'if the client uses the self-signed certificate'.

Comment: @bguiz Order of certificate is important in concatenated file. Did you try all the combinations?

Comment: I have tried both of `cert: grunt.file.read('server.crt').toString() + grunt.file.read('bundle.crt').toString(),` and `cert: grunt.file.read('bundle.crt').toString() + grunt.file.read('server.crt').toString(),`... neither worked.

Comment: Jakub, if you could put together a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) `Gruntfile` with connect configured to accept a server certificate and bundle certificate and demonstrate how to do this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @bguiz I don't have proper experience in grunt, but one last thing I would try is adding `'\n'` (newline) between certs while concatenating. Or using text editor to do so.